# Dynamically calling Canvas Functions

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is there any way to call canvas functions using apply() or a similar method, as to dynamically call canvas methods or to be able to pass an array of arguments?

Im looking for this effect
`context.fillRect.apply(this,args);`

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you call them directly?

Comment: You can, but like I said, I want to be to call them dynamically using a function string or an array of arguments. This way I dont need to create two separate functions for similar operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
var op = "fillRect";    
var args = [
  10, 10, 180, 180  
];
ctx[op].apply(ctx, args);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eZwYQ/

Comment: Right, my problem was passing `this` as the first argument to `apply()`. Obvious mistake in hindsight but thanks again for the answer!

Comment: No worries; when I tried your example I just Google'd the error Chrome was throwing and found another SO question that discussed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

your `apply` method should work just fine :

```
function rectangle(){
    ctx.fillRect.apply(ctx,arguments);
}
```

And of course this can get more "*dynamic*" :

```
function doSomethingWithCanvas(context,action,arg1,arg2/*,...argn*/){
    context[action].apply(context,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2));
}
```

And you could use the same function to fill a rectangle, to draw a circle or to draw a simple line :

```
// simple line
doSomethingWithCanvas(ctx,'lineTo',10, 100);

// circle
doSomethingWithCanvas(ctx,'arc',275, 275, 200, 0, Math.PI*2, true);

// fillRect
doSomethingWithCanvas(ctx,'fillRect,10, 10, 180, 180);
```

PS :  by providing the canvas context as an argument, you can use this function to draw on any canvas.